# how to insert data to specific user and access their own data in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm a new in Girebase. In my Ionic2 app, I'm trying to do this:

When user log in with Facebook, it takes his data and takes the ID and put it inside Firebase. Then I want to add to specific ID, notes he added.
I succeeded to do all of that but when I logout from user I log in again and all the data remove(all his notes).

I understand why it's happened because every time I log in with user, it's call again to Firebase to see the ID, name and photo then it just remove the details before.

Okay so this is my Firebase structure
[image]

That's my facebook login code(it works fine)

```
   facebookLogin(){

    Facebook.login(['email']).then( (response) => {
      let facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
          .credential(response.authResponse.accessToken);
      var that = this;
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
          .then((success) => {
            console.log("Firebase success: " + JSON.stringify(success));  
            that.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Firebase failure: " + JSON.stringify(error));
          });

    }).catch((error) => { console.log(error) });
  }
```

This is home.ts
(just explain before: everytime the HomePage called so it's go to set data profile again-- maybe because that the problem)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController,NavParams,LoadingController,AlertController,ViewController  } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Facebook } from 'ionic-native';

//import pages
import {LoginPage} from "../../pages/login/login";
import {User} from '../../models/user'

//import provider
import { ProfileData } from '../../providers/profile-data';
import { NotesData } from '../../providers/notes-data';

import firebase from 'firebase'
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
  //facebook user
  userProfile: any = null;
  uid: any = null;
  fireUid:any=null;
  name:string=null;
  photo: any = null;
  user:User=null;

  //notes list

  notes:any=null;
  data:any;



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public profileData:ProfileData,private viewCtrl: ViewController,public notesData:NotesData,private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.data={};
    this.data.title="";
    this.data.desc="";
  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.fireUid=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    this.getDetailsFacebook();
    this.getNotesList();
  }

//facebook functions
  getDetailsFacebook() {
    var that=this;
    Facebook.getLoginStatus().then((response)=> {
      if (response.status == 'connected') {
        Facebook.api('/' + response.authResponse.userID + '?fields=id,name,gender', []).then((response)=> {
          //alert(JSON.stringify(response));
         that.uid = response.id;
          that.name=response.name;
         that.photo = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+that.uid+"/picture?type=large";
          that.user=new User(that.uid,that.fireUid,that.name, that.photo);
          that.profileData.setProfileData(that.user); // to create class for that

          //that.profileData.setProfile(that.uid,that.name,that.photo);
          //console.log("id:"+this.uid+this.name+this.photo);
        }, (error)=> {
          alert(error);
        })
      }
      else {
        alert('Not Logged in');
      }
    })


  }
  getPhoto() {
    var that=this;
    Facebook.getLoginStatus().then((response)=> {
      if (response.status == 'connected') {
        Facebook.api('/me', []).then((response)=> {
          alert(JSON.stringify(response));
          that.photo = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+response.that.uid+"/picture";
        }, (error)=> {
          alert(error);
        })
      }
      else {
        alert('Not Logged in');
      }
    })


  }
  logOutFacebook(){
    Facebook.logout().then((response)=>
    {
      this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
      alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },(error)=>{
      alert(error);
    })
  }

  //notes functions
  getNotesList(){
    console.log("get event");
    var that=this;
    this.notesData.getNotesLIst().on('value', snapshot => {
      let notesList= [];
      snapshot.forEach( snap => {
        console.log("id note"+snap.val().id);
        notesList.push({
          id: snap.val().id,
          title: snap.val().title,
          desc: snap.val().desc,
        });
      });
      that.notes = notesList;
    });
  }
  addNotes() {
    //add preloader

    console.log(this.data.title,this.data.desc);
    this.notesData.createNote(this.data.title, this.data.desc);

    }

  delete(id:number){
  }
  update(id:number){}
}
```

that's my profile-data provider

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import firebase from 'firebase'

//import pages
import {User} from '../models/user'
/*
  Generated class for the ProfileData provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/

@Injectable()
export class ProfileData {

  public userProfile: any;
  public currentUser: any;

  constructor() {
    this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser; // We'll use this to create a database reference to the userProfile node.
    this.userProfile = firebase.database().ref('/users'); // We'll use this to create an auth reference to the current user.
  }
  setProfileData(userObj:User){
    this.userProfile.child(userObj.fireUid).set({
      firstname:userObj.full_name,
      photoURl:userObj.photo
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create "notes" outside of "users". You can put the userID inside "notes" and this way you can save this information.

Becuase "users" only save the username, id and phototuri.